# Java Spring Stomp AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, stomp, sockjs

I have three project:

1. Javascript SockJS STOMP client
2. Spring-boot STOMP endpoint and AMQP
3. Spring-boot AMQP (RabbitListener) client for testing

   I am using RabbitMQ message broker (+Stomp plugin) and configured ***amqp*** and ***stomp*** endpoint normally..When I send message to queue with **RabbitTemplate** and third project (spring-boot amqp client for testing) normally subscribed this message , everything works fine !! But Javascript STOMP client didn't received this message..
   P.S. When I send message with **SimpMessagingTemplate**  , JS client receives message fine !

**Javascript SockJS STOMP Client**

```
        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8090/hello');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect('guest','guest', function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/testqueue', function(greeting){
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
```

**spring-boot STOMP endpoint and AMQP**

```
    @Controller
    public class SampleController {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleController.class);
    
        @Autowired
        private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    
        private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    
        @Autowired
        public SampleController(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate) {
            this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/emit/{message}")
        @ResponseBody
        String queue1(@PathVariable("message") String message) throws Exception {
            logger.info("Emit to testqueue");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/testqueue", new Greeting("Salam olsun " + message));
            Thread.sleep(60000); // simulated delay
            return "Emit to testqueue";
        }
}
```

**spring-boot amqp client for testing**

```
@Component
public class RabbitMqListener {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RabbitMqListener.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "/topic/testqueue")
    public void processQueue1(String message) {
        logger.info("Received from queue : " + message);
    }
}
```

How I can mix amqp and stomp protocols in RabbitMQ ? I want to send message from another project with amqp protocol (RabbitTemplate) and receive this message from JS STOMP client (SockJS) .. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have somewhere an `enableStompBrokerRelay()` in your application configurations:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay?

Comment: of course.. I implemented RabbitMQ with enableStompBrokerRelay . (host,port,username,password)

Comment: Any chances that you can share with us some simple project on GitHub to let us to play with it and reproduce what you are worry about? Would be also great to have some README there with an instruction what to do to reproduce.

Comment: oh , thanks Artem..I will try to share some projects in Github soon.

Comment: Please, try also to figure out what you are missing when you mix AMQP and STOMP protocols: https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html. Especially pay attention to the `For SEND frames, the message is sent to the amq.topic exchange with the routing key <name>.` . So, your `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/testqueue", ...)` doesn't sound right.

Comment: There is also this to study a bit: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/

Comment: Thanks Artem , I was changed rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/testqueue", ...) to rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("amqp.topic","testqueue" ...) and everythink works fine )))

Comment: Cool! You can answer to your own question and accept it. I will also up-vote that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was changed `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/testqueue", ...)` to `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("amq.topic","testqueue" ...)` and everythink works fine ))) Especially thanks to Artem Bilan for support. Good Luck